# I have an exercise of c

Tags: c, arrays

My exercise is input list integer numbers from keyboard and the end of program by 0. Then print sum of array. This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

const int MAX_ITEMS = 50;
void inputIntegerNumber(int* a, int* count);
int sumOfInteger(int* n, int* count);

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int x[MAX_ITEMS], count;

    inputIntegerNumber(&x, &count);
    printf("Sum of array is %d", sumOfInteger(&x, &count));

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

void inputIntegerNumber(int* a, int* count ){
    do{
        printf("Please! input numbers: ");
        scanf("%d", a);
        *count++;
    }while((*a != 0) && (*count != MAX_ITEMS));

}

int sumOfInteger(int* n, int* count){
    int sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < *count; i++)
        sum += *n;

    return sum;
}
```

I don't know what's wrong with it? It doesn't give me a result same my thinks...

Comment: For starters `*count++;` -> `(*count)++;` See C *Operator Precedence*.

Comment: When asking such a question, please define *very clearly* what is your input, expected output and actual output.

Comment: Turn on compiler warnings. The compiler will tell you some of the things that are wrong. Another thing that is wrong is that you never access any array element beyond the first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some problems like -

```
 inputIntegerNumber(&x, &count);
 printf("Sum of array is %d", sumOfInteger(&x, &count));
```

in both calls you pass `&x` but `x` is an array of `int` and your function expects `int *` not `int (*)[]`. This must have given an error atleast.

For both functions you can just pass the array `x` directly.

And in your function `inputIntegerNumber` this -

```
 *count++;
```

You need to increment value of `count`, so it should be `(*count)++`. Dereference first and then increment the value.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing some mistakes in your code like passing pointer to a pointer `&x` value(since array is basically a pointer to some memory location) and overwriting the same location again and again. In `scanf("%d", a);` you are overwriting the first location again and again without changing `a` in you input loop.You need to learn about arrays and their usage. In `sumOfInteger` function also you're not changing the value of `n`. I changed you code a bit and i was able to see desired output.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

const int MAX_ITEMS = 50;
void inputIntegerNumber(int* a, int* count);
int sumOfInteger(int* n, int* count);

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int x[MAX_ITEMS], count = 0; // zero elements in array

    inputIntegerNumber(x, &count);
    printf("Sum of array is %d", sumOfInteger(x, &count));

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

void inputIntegerNumber(int* a, int* count ){
    int aIndex = 0;
    do{
        printf("Please! input numbers: ");
        scanf("%d", &a[aIndex]);
        aIndex++;
    }while((a[aIndex-1] != 0) && (aIndex != MAX_ITEMS));

    *count = aIndex;
}

int sumOfInteger(int* n, int* count){
    int sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < *count; i++)
        sum += n[i];

    return sum;
}
```

when i run it i can see :

```
~/Documents/src : $ ./a.out 
    Please! input numbers: 1
    Please! input numbers: 2
    Please! input numbers: 3
    Please! input numbers: 0
    Sum of array is 6
```

Answer (score 0):

You're overcomplicating things. Before you sit down to write a program, always write the general steps that must be done

- Read the numbers from the command line
- Convert them to ints and save them in memory
- Calculate the sum
- Print it

Here is the revised program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> /* for strtol */

#define DIE(msg) fprintf(stderr, "%s", msg); exit(EXIT_FAILURE)

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int *nums;

    if (argc <= 1)
        DIE("Usage: [int-list]\n");

    /* skip program name */
    --argc;
    ++argv;

    nums = malloc(argc * sizeof(int));
    if (!nums)
        DIE("Out of mem\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < argc; ++i) {
        char *end;
        double val = strtol(argv[i], &end, 0);

        if (end == argv[i]) /* no digits detected */
            DIE("Usage: [int-list]\n");

        nums[i] = val;
    }
    printf("%d\n", add(nums, argc));

    free(nums);
}
int add(int arr[], size_t n)
{
    int sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        sum += arr[i];

    return sum;
}
```

To complete the [`strtol`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtol.3.html) error handling is an exercise for the OP.